# Looking for a "Guide for the Perplexed by Low-dimensional Topology"

Tags: reference-request, low-dimensional-topology

The following excerpt is from pp. 56-57 of Loring Tu's (so far very enjoyable) textbook [*An Introduction to Manifolds* (2nd ed.)](https://books.google.com/books?id=xQsTJJGsgs4C):

> One of the most surprising achievements in topology was John Milnor’s discovery [...] in 1956 of exotic $7$-spheres, smooth manifolds homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic to the standard $7$-sphere. In 1963, Michel Kervaire and John Milnor [...] determined that there are exactly 28 nondiffeomorphic differentiable structures on $S^7$.
>
> It is known that in dimensions $< 4$ every topological manifold has a unique differentiable structure and in dimensions $> 4$ every compact topological manifold has a finite number of differentiable structures.  Dimension 4 is a mystery.  It is not known whether $S^4$ has a finite or infinite number of differentiable structures. The statement that $S^4$ has a unique differentiable structure is called *the smooth Poincaré conjecture*.  As of this writing in 2010, the conjecture is still open.
>
> There are topological manifolds with no differentiable structure. Michel Kervaire was the first to construct an example [...].

For a layperson like myself these are unsettling revelations.  In fact, the mere *existence* of a field of research devoted specifically to low-dimensional topology is already unsettling enough<sup>1</sup>.

What accounts for this distinction between low- and high-dimensional topology?  What's up with dimension 4?  Is $\mathbb{R}^4$ (or $\mathbb{C}^4$ or $\mathbb{H}^4$) topologically exceptional as well?

I have searched online, without success, for a textbook that addresses itself to these questions.  Any suggestions?

Alternatively, is there a guide to the proofs of the items mentioned in the excerpt above (or at least of the ones about the number of differentiable structures on $4$-manifolds)?

Either way, I'm interested in a textbook-like treatment (with proofs) aimed at someone whose mathematical level is roughly that of Tu's textbook<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Then again, there's this business with the quintic, which I don't yet understand...  I wonder if there's any known connection between these two unexpected "dividing lines" in $\mathbb{N}$.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup>Tu's textbook, true to its promise to stick to the essentials of its subject, does not elaborate on any of the quoted findings.</sub>

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^4$ is certainly special. On $\mathbb{R}^n$, if $n\neq 4$, all differentiable structures are diffeomorphic. [On $\mathbb{R}^4$, there exist (infinitely many) pairwise non-diffeomorphic differentiable structures.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_R4)

Comment: Every dimension has its own special properties.  For example, knots are deep and interesting only in $\mathbb R^3$.  In $\mathbb R^4$ and higher all knots are the same.  So the fact that some things are true just about $\Bbb R^4$ shouldn't be unsettling.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: At least part of the reason I find this stuff unsettling is that pretty much everywhere else (outside of areas devoted to these dimension-specific peculiarities) the sets $\mathbb{R}^n$ are treated as "basically the same" modulo a "trivial" difference in the dimensions.  In particular, people routinely reason about "$\mathbb{R}^n$" (for some unspecified $n$) by analogy with their intuitions about $\mathbb{R}^d$ for $d \in \{1, 2, 3\}$.  If every dimension has its own quirks, such thinking by analogy (where the target of the analogy is wholly unfamiliar) becomes highly suspect.

Comment: @kjo Yes, thinking by analogy is dangerous.  Let me give you a telling example.  In $\Bbb R^3$ it is intuitively obvious that two 2-dimensional planes intersect in a line.  That seems so natural that we feel it must be true in any dimension three or higher.  But in fact two 2-dimensional planes in $\Bbb R^4$ can intersect in a single point.  Can you picture that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend Scorpan's *The Wild World of 4-manifolds*. As the title suggests, it's mainly centered on dimension 4, but in its first part, it does a superb job at explaining what is special about low dimensions.